# SSRS Excel Export (Excel function Hide/unhide)

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to export a SSRS Report in Excel, but it should be possible to unhide the Column.
So if I export the column is hidden and it should be possible to unhide this Excel Column (like the picture) [image]

with VBA it's possible with this function:

Columns("D").Hidden = True

Do you have an idea how to solve it in SSRS ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this to work, you should enable a textbox that can toggle visibility (this will also work in your report)

In my example column3 visibility is toggled by column1 header textbox

[image]

[image]

[image]